# Inserting a new line at a specific row with a tab in bash script using sed, along with env variable

Tags: bash, sed

I have a part of json which looks like below:

```
{
  "openstack": {
    "admin": {
      "username": "admin",
      "password": "password",
      "tenant_name": "test"
    },
```

and three environment variables defined like this

```
auth_url=VALUE1
region_name=VALUE3
endpoint_type=VALUE2
```

I want to insert 3 lines in the input file just after row 2, so that the output is

```
{
  "openstack": {
    "auth_url": VALUE1,
    "region_name": VALUE2,
    "endpoint_type": VALUE3,
    "admin": {
      "username": "admin",
      "password": "password",
      "tenant_name": "test"
    },
```

How it can be done using SED, I tried below

```
sed -e '3i/\t"auth_url":$auth_url,' -i account_2.json
```

But it not only adds an extra `/` at row no 3 but it also doesn't actually replace `$auth_url` with environment variable as well.

Comment: This has to be in a bash script

Comment: Instead of line-oriented tools, use a syntax-aware tool like [tag:jq] for parsing/manipulating JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are are misusing the `i` command. You have to put backslash after it, not a slash.

Furhtermore, the variable is not expanded since it is in single quotes. Try putting it in double quotes, like this

```
sed "3i\    \"auth_url\":$AUTH," yourfile
```

I've read that the `i`nsert command wants whatever follows the backslash to be on a newline, which is not the case here, where we have everything on a single line. I guess that's GNU sed's which allows it.

To insert three lines, you can use this

```
sed "3i\    \"auth_url\":$SHELL\n    \"auth_url\":$SHELL\n    \"auth_url\":$SHELL" os
```

And it works well with commas too, since they have no special meaning:

```
sed "3i\    \"auth_url\":$SHELL,\n    \"auth_url\":$SHELL,\n    \"auth_url\":$SHELL,"
```

Comment: This is giving an error while using with , (comma)
```
sed "3i\    \"auth_url\":$AUTH_URL,\n    \"region_name\":$REGION_NAME,\n    \"endpoint_type\":$OS_INTERFACE," -i "${ACCOUNTS_JSON}"
```
sed error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 45: unknown command: `,'

Comment: @SaurabhArora, I have copied your command, except for `-i "${ACCOUNTS_JSON}"` and it correctly works and prints to stdout. Please, try stop formatting code in comments with backticks. And don't put too long code in the comments anyway.

Comment: @ Enrico Maria De Angelis: I found the issue, the issue is with the URL: https://identity-nc.xxx, if it is getting replaced with the variable name $SHELL and that is causing issue with sed, any clue how to fix this up

Comment: @SaurabhArora this is a different topic, for which you can post a new question. In the meantime I have answered your question correctly already.

Comment: Agree, however I found the the resolution using jq